# Maximum policy size error from serverless framework

Tags: lambda, serverless

Deploying a sizeable serverless application, we had first hit the cap of 200 resources. we using `serverless-plugin-split-stacks` library solved that issue but possibly introduced another one later on:

> An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - Maximum policy size of
>   10240 bytes exceeded for role
>   pca-console-production-ap-northeast-2-lambdaRole (Service:
>   AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 409; Error Code: LimitExceeded;

This errors related a code lines?

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is common when the AWS Iam Role you are creating becomes too large. It has a max set size. The same thing would happen if you created an AWS IAMRole via inline json and the policy became too large. Either reduce the IAMRole Policy size or break it up into several policies.

Comment: With serverless framework you really cannot do that...